# How to "Remove the Textareas by clicking a button" in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

- As Im new to react, I want to perform delete operations.
- I have four textareas and delete button on the right side.
- If i click on delete button the specific textarea should be deleted.
- The code :

```js
import React,{Component} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
class App extends Component {
 
  handleRemove(){

  }
 render()
 {
  
return(
  <div>
   <div>
   <input
    className="textstyle"  
   /> 
   <button onClick={()=>this.handleRemove()}>Delete</button> 
   </div>
   <div>
   <input
   className="textstyle"  
   /> 
  <button onClick={()=>this.handleRemove()}>Delete</button> 
  </div>
<div>
 <input
 className="textstyle"  
 /> 
<button onClick={()=>this.handleRemove()}>Delete</button> 
</div>
<div>
<input
 className="textstyle"  
/> 
<button onClick={()=>this.handleRemove()}>Delete</button> 
</div>
</div>
)
}
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below approach,

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
 class App extends Component {
  state = {
    removedId: []
  };

  handleRemove(id) {
    this.setState((prev) => ({ ...prev, removedId: [...prev.removedId, id] 
   }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          {!this.state.removedId.includes(1) && (
            <>
              <input className="textstyle" />
              <button onClick={() => this.handleRemove(1)}>Delete</button>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
        <div>
          {!this.state.removedId.includes(2) && (
            <>
              <input className="textstyle" />
              <button onClick={() => this.handleRemove(2)}>Delete</button>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
        <div>
          {!this.state.removedId.includes(3) && (
            <>
              <input className="textstyle" />
              <button onClick={() => this.handleRemove(3)}>Delete</button>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
        <div>
          {!this.state.removedId.includes(4) && (
            <>
              <input className="textstyle" />
              <button onClick={() => this.handleRemove(4)}>Delete</button>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Working Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/patient-silence-nr9ou?file=/src/App.js:0-1020

Comment: Thanks @UKS it is working... I have one doubt ..How to delete that whole div including delete button also.

Comment: I have updated the code. Let me know if you are facing case any issues.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using an optimized way for such things as below-

improved your code

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    lists: [
      { id: 1, show: true },
      { id: 2, show: true },
      { id: 3, show: true },
      { id: 4, show: true }
    ]
  };
  handleDelete = (item) => {
    let updated = this.state.lists.filter((list) => list.id !== item.id);
    this.setState({ lists: updated });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        {this.state.lists.map((list, indx) => (
          <React.Fragment key={indx}>
            <div>
              <input type="textarea" placeholder="Enter something" />
              <button onClick={() => this.handleDelete(list)}>Delete</button>
            </div>
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[Live working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/remove-area-on-delete-hbk6f?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Thanks @Vahid Akhtar But the delete operation is not working correctly

Comment: @Pooja you don't need to delete just filter it and update the same array. if you want a permanent deletion, handle with local storage or API call.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to keep it functional component and leverage ReactHooks (`useState`) instead going to class based component.

Here you go:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState([
    {
      id: "uniqueid_1",
      name: "textarea-1",
      value: ""
    },
    {
      id: "uniqueid_2",
      name: "textarea-2",
      value: "seomthing"
    }
  ]);

  const handleRemove = (index) => {
    let array = [...rows]; // make a separate copy of the array
    if (index !== -1) {
      array.splice(index, 1);
      setRows(array);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        {rows.map((row, index) => {
          return (
            <div key={row.id}>
              <input name={row.name} className="textstyle" />
              <button onClick={() => handleRemove(index)}>Delete</button>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```